# get ios push deviceToken second time

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push, devicetoken

I need to get deviceToken.
When I added push notification to my app I received deviceToken via `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

but now I need to get it again and i didnt save is. 
`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` calls just once and other times app runs just `registerUserNotificationSettings`

I thought to save tokens from all new users to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` but it will work just for new ones. What to do with current users?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in “didFinishLaunchingWithOptions” method…

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} 
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Then “didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken” method will be called on every call of “didFinishLaunchingWithOptions” during app launching.